# Expected Identifier or "(" CLLocation in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, cllocationmanager

I'm building my first app, and I can't tell if this is a bug, or where the problem is.  Been checking SO and the goog for hours, but can't track down this specific fix.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "AppDelegate.m"
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
@end

@interface CLLocationManagerDelegate : CLLocationManager
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManagerDelegate *locationManager;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController;
- (IBAction)Parked:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)WheresMyCar:(id)sender {
}
@end


@implementation CLLocationManagerDelegate;
{ **error is here, expected identifier or )**

-   (void)startStandardUpdates
if (nil == locationManager)
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 250;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
//recent event, turn off updates to save power
CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
//if event is recent, do something with it
if (abs(howRecent) <15.0) {
    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
@end
```

Comment: The `{` on the error line should be after the method name `startStandardUpdates`.  But are you **sure** you want to create a _subclass_ of CLLocationManager and use the name "CLLocationManagerDelegate" for that subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but there are so many issuea wrong with this code.

Remove the `;` from the end of `@implementation CLLocationManagerDelegate;` and `@implementation ViewController;` and get rid of the `{` and `}` from `@implementation ViewController; {` and `} @end`

This method `- (void)startStandardUpdates` is also missing the `{ }` brackets replace

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // if(nil == locationManager) This is just silly change to below
    if (locationManager == nil) 
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; // Because there are no {} wrapping this if statement this is the only line that will run if locationManager is nil

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 250;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
}
```

**Side Notes**

When it comes to convention the a method should be declared with the first letter as lower case so the below methods

```
- (IBAction)Parked:(id)sender { }
- (IBAction)WheresMyCar:(id)sender { }
```

should become

```
- (IBAction)parked:(id)sender { }
- (IBAction)wheresMyCar:(id)sender { }
```

Since your subclassing `CLLocationManager` I wouldn't recommend using the name `CLLocationManagerDelegate` this could create some confusion. I would recommend something along the lines of just `@interface LocationManager : CLLocationManager` or prefix it with the something else like company initials, so for the company I work for this would become `@interface PPDLocationManager : CLLocationManager` Also the reason behind why you shouldn't be using the name `CLLocationManagerDelegate` as your class is because it is already a protocol name see the [Apple Documentation for `CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)

The Below methods are in the wrong `@implementation`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

they should be in your `ViewController` implementation not your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` implementation.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)  I got it up and running...now to tweak it.